# Python pass list as argument sends all of list data or just reference

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def test(a):
  a.append(3)

test_list = [1,2]
test(test_list)
```

In the above code, when I pass test_list as an argument to test function, does python send the whole list object/data (which is a big byte size) or just the reference to the list (which would be much smaller since its just a pointer)?

From what I understood by looking at Python's pass by object reference, it only sends the reference, but do not know how to verify that it indeed is the case

Comment: In the case of a list, it will be passed by reference. You can check `id` of the object outside and inside the function.

Comment: @pavel: In the case of *everything* it's passed by reference (in the non-C++ sense of the word). It's just that for immutable types, you can't do anything to them that would expose the fact that the argument holds an alias to the caller's value besides checking the `id` (anything that seemingly mutates them is really constructing a new object and rebinding the function's name, leaving the caller untouched; if you receive an `int`, `argint += 1` is internally implemented to construct a new object and bind it to `argint`, while `arglist += [1]` modifies in place, rebinding the original `list`).

Answer (score 2):

It's passing an alias to the function; for the life of the function, or until the function intentionally rebinds `a` to point to something else (with `a = something`), the function's `a` is an alias to the same `list` bound to the caller's `test_list`.

The straightforward ways to confirm this are:

1. Print `test_list` after the call; if the `list` were actually copied, the `append` in the function would only affect the copy, the caller wouldn't see it. `test_list` will in fact have had a new element appended, so it was the same `list` in the function.
2. Print `id(test_list)` outside the function, and `id(a)` inside the function; `id`s are required to be unique at any given point in time, so the only way two *different* `list`s could have the same ID is if one was destroyed before the other was created; since `test_list` continues to exist before and after the function call, if `a` has the same `id`, it's definitionally the same `list`.

Answer (score 1):

All function arguments are passed by reference in Python.  So the `a` variable in the function `test` will refer to the same object as `test_list` does in the calling code.  After the function returns, `test_list` will contain `[1,2,3]`.